# Loading data from a link processed by JavaScript (using a script)

Tags: node.js, parsing, web-scraping, blob, export-to-csv

I want to download data from [this page](https://www.tradingview.com/screener/) using the script

On the page there is a button for exporting data to CSV file  - ***Export data screener to a CSV file***, but it does not have a link I could use for downloading since the click on this button is processed by the JavaScript function at the time of the click.

On the output, I get the following link on which the file `blob: https: //www.tradingview.com/1e82c571-fbf7-4cd0-9a4c-8c836263e17`

Tell me how i can implement downloading a file from a script, for example, written on the **NodeJS**. Do not wait for the finished code at least where you can see ....

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It would be better if you find an Stock Web API and get the data from there.

Comment: @Tony on this page the TV generates signals (RATING colomn).  These signals are what I need and not just price data.   If the question were in obtaining OHLСV, I would not ask a question. I need the CSV which I will save and then analyze

Comment: Yes, I mean, usually those things have a service where you can connect and obtain the feed. (I did not downvote)

Comment: @Tony In this case, it counts the service itself and no one else. There are no other sources. Or you need to release the calculation of all indicators.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can take.

1. Find an alternative way to get the data. They may have a direct download URL or API that you can call. Screen scraping is a hacky way to get access to the data, and it may be against their site's license agreement.
2. Because the download button is JavaScript based, you can use a real browser to open the page and click the button. The[`phantom` node wrapper](http://amirraminfar.com/phantomjs-node/#/) is one way you can interface a node script with PhantomJS and automate this.
3. Probably the easiest thing to do is to reverse-engineer what clicking the button does using developer tools, then follow those same steps in node code. For example, you can view the network tab to see what request(s) are made, then duplicate those same requests.